# How do I flatten the multi object data and map to a JSON schema uisng reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsonschema

I want to generate a form of json schema and map the value.

```
'queues.bootStrapServers': {
   title: 'BootStrap Servers',
   type: 'array',
   items: { 
     type : "object", 
     properties :{
       'hostUrl' : {
          type : "string"
       }
     }
   }
},
```

UI schema

```
'queues.bootStrapServers': {
   'ui:widget': 'CustomTextWidget',
   classNames: 'customwidth_48',
   'ui:options': { type: 'text', placeholder: 'Enter BootStrap Servers' },
 },

 {
   queues.bootStrapServers[0].hostUrl: "kafka://100.200.300.55:6251"
   queues.bootStrapServers[1].hostUrl: "kafka://100.200.300.56:6251"
   queues.bootStrapServers[2].hostUrl: "kafka://100.200.300.57:6251"
 }
```

Unable to display the value

Comment: You are trying to access an index of a non-array to set a value? That isn't possible. `queue.bootStapServers` returns an _object_, and you would want to access `items`, and yet that also is not an array. Another thing too, react is unrelated to this problem.

Comment: @Kobe - Wat is the solution for this ?

Comment: Just use an array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible structure of your schema:

```
'queues.bootStrapServers': {
   title: 'BootStrap Servers',
   type: 'array',
   items: [
     { 
     type : "object", 
     properties :{
       'hostUrl' : {
          type : "string"
       }
     }
   },
   {
     type : "object", 
     properties :{
       'hostUrl' : {
          type : "string"
       }
     }
   }
  ]
},
```